# Create 3 price boxes with Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to create 3 boxes with equal height using Bootstrap but I am not sure how to do it.

I found I can use flexbox and my main boxes will be equal height but I want some inner div to have border and that div to fill the main div and I cannot do it.

I have also some other problems: how to position button at the center bottom of that div and I have there also some description paragraph and I would like those paragrahps also to be equal heights, because I use some border at the bottom.

Here is my example code:

```
<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="box-header">
        </div>
        <div class="box-body">
          <p class="box-info">Some description of product 1</p>
          <ul class="box-list">
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
          </ul>
          <button class="btn btn-default">Register</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="box-header">
        </div>
        <div class="box-body">
          <p class="box-info">Some description of product 2 which can be very loooooooooooooong</p>
          <ul class="box-list">
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
          </ul>
          <button class="btn btn-default">Register</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="box-header">
        </div>
        <div class="box-body">
          <p class="box-info">Some description of product 3</p>
          <ul class="box-list">
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
          </ul>
          <button class="btn btn-default">Register</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><!-- /.container -->
```

Css:

```
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.box-header {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: center;
}
.box-body {
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 30px;  
    border: 1px solid green;
    border-top: none;
}

.box-info {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
}
.box-list {
    text-align: left;
}
```

My description can not be clear, so you can find a [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/qog7sjtPIF) here.

Comment: As a heads up, links to Sandboxes (Bootply, JSFiddle, etc) are good, but you also must post the relevant code in your question. If the link ever gets removed, your question becomes invalid.